# Doctrine 2 command line tool; MAMP and mysql.sock

Tags: mysql, database, sockets, mamp, mysql.sock

I grabbed the CI2/Doctrine2 from [Wildly Inaccurate](http://www.wildlyinaccurate.com). I'm trying to start using it, but before I'm actually getting to work with it, I wanted to make sure everything works. However, when I try the command line tool, I run into the following error:

```
$ ./doctrine orm:schema-tool:create

ATTENTION: This operation should not be executed in a production environment.

Creating database schema...

Warning: PDO::__construct(): [2002] Socket operation on non-socket (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock) in /Users/joris/Desktop/ci2_starter/application/libraries/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php on line 36



  [PDOException]                                         
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Socket operation on non-socket  



orm:schema-tool:create [--dump-sql]
```

I'm running this on a cleanly installed MAMP Pro 2.0.1; I'm not really sure what to do to fix this error.. I'm not really knowledgeable on the inner (background) workings of MySQL. Could someone clear this up for me? Thanks a lot.

Update:

```
MacBook-Pro-van-Joris-Ooms:~ joris$ sudo find / -name 'mysql.sock'
Password:
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
/private/var/mysql/mysql.sock
/private/var/mysql/mysql.sock/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MAMP does use it's own mysql socket while the CLi uses the default one in /var/mysql/mysql.sock.
This could mean you are running the wrong PHP version (not the MAMP one but the default MAC OS X one). Not a big deal since it can deal with your Doctrine Command Line Issues as well.
So you do have several options:

1. try using the MAMP php version to start the CLi tool by putting the Path to your MAC OS X php version as a prefix i.e.

   /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php ./doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
2. just set up a link from /var/mysql/mysql.sock to the actual Socket file which should be in /Applications/MAMP//tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
   So you go to the terminal while your MAMP is running an type (You will be asked to type in a password):

   sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP//tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
3. Find every occurrence of "/Applications/MAMP//tmp/mysql/mysql.sock" in any of your MAMP config files and change it to be /var/mysql/mysql.sock so you actually do use the default address for MySQL Socket. Though, i have never tested if this does work.

Comment: Trying the first option, I get this: ln: /var/mysql/mysql.sock/mysql.sock: File exists. Thanks for the reply, btw.

Comment: @cabaret: Could you try to find all the mysql.sock files on your system?
Use this line:
sudo find / -name 'mysql.sock'

Comment: I updated my original post with the result, as it's a bit much to put in a comment.

Comment: The first option with the prefix worked.. However, isn't there an easier way to fix this? I gave you the bounty and accepted the answer though, because only one hour left and well, it works, even though it's a lot to type ;D

Comment: @cabaret: You could ty and your MAMPs php to the default folder where the MAC php is located.

Comment: The second option worked for me - thanks! The only tweak was the location of my /var... my command was:  sudo ln -s /applications/mamp//tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /usr/local/var/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: Thanks, for me the full command was /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.19/bin/php vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create