# getting "db: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused" error on Mac with MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, macos, localhost

I am trying to run the CLI version of this PHP databse [Search and Replace Script](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB), but I think this a more general MySQL problem relating to Mac OS X and MAMP. I receive the following error whenever I attempt to run the CLI script locally:

```
db: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

Here is the command I'm running:

```
./srdb.cli.php -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -n mydbname -proot -c utf\-8 -s mywebsite.com -r dev.mywebsite.com
```

**What I've tried**

- I am able to connect to mysql using these settings, no problem, using `mysql -u root -proot` etc...
- Swapping 127.0.0.1 for localhost gives the same error.
- All my my.cnf files are blank.
- Apache and MySQL are running fine.
- I have succeeded in replicating this problem on another Mac running MAMP

I am using this `mysql`: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql

And this `php`: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.28/bin/php

Anybody any ideas? Thanks!

**Edit**

Here is the source code showing how the script connects to MySQL:
https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/blob/master/srdb.cli.php

which in turn imports this:

https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/blob/master/srdb.class.php

Comment: How do you access MySQL via PHP? Can you post the code?

Comment: In srcb.class.php, add this code after line 383: print $connection_type."\n\n"; . Then, on line 414 ($connection = @mysql_connect(...)), remove @ sign. Final run your script again and see what happens.

Comment: This could be a problem with PHP and MAMP using different socket loactions. The answer to the following question could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461360/doctrine-2-command-line-tool-mamp-and-mysql-sock

Comment: And another idea: Are you really sure, you're running the MAMP provided php binary? The shebang line in `srdb.cli.php` reads `#!/usr/bin/php`and that points to the Apple-provided php binary.

Comment: @z80crew: oh dear, that was the answer. I thought I was using MAMP's php, but you're right, the shebang line was defaulting to the system's PHP. Please provide that as an answer and I'll upvote it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated in my comment already, chances are that you're not running the PHP binary you thought you were running. Even if the MAMP php binary is in your path, the shebang line in `srdb.cli.php` reads `#!/usr/bin/php` and that points to the Apple-provided php binary.

So if you invoke the script with the full path to your MAMP php binary, the problem should be avoided:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.28/bin/php srdb.cli.php -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -n mydbname -proot -c utf\-8 -s mywebsite.com -r dev.mywebsite.com
```

Another solution might be to replace the shebang line with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

This works only if the MAMP binary is in your $PATH in front of `/usr/bin`. Using `#!/usr/bin/env php`ensures however, that you're always using the same binary no matter if you're invoking the script via `./srdb.cli.php` or with `php srdb.cli.php`.

Comment: thanks for the extra info. I don't have the luxury of being able to edit the shebang line, because this script is hosted in a public repo and I download it again each time I want to use it. The previous workaround I was using was to issue a `sed` command to replace the shebang line with one of my choosing. Your solution is much simpler however, I didn't realize you could execute PHP scripts like this: `path/to/my/php script.php ...`. Very useful.

Comment: THANKS BROTHER !

Answer (score 1):

Stop mysql :

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

And then start it :

```
sudo service mysql start
```

It resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

To add onto z80crew's brilliant solution, for anyone else unfamiliar/uncomfortable with altering path variables, specifying the **full location paths** for *both* the MAMP php binary and the search-replace-db script in the cli script provided by interconnect solved the problem for me. I put the strings to search for and replace with in quotes. I also increased the php timeout limit in wp-config.php with: set_time_limit(3000);

I was consistent with the server name between the options passed to the script and what's in my wp-config.php file (using localhost in wp-config, using localhost in the script as well)

`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.2/bin/php /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/Search-Replace-DB-master/srdb.cli.php -h localhost -u root -proot --port 8889 -n test -s "http://olddomain.com" -r "http://localhost:8888/test" -v true`